# Creating a Log-In Screen with Validation?

Tags: java, swing, security, user-interface, encryption

I'm creating a Java log-in screen for a scheduling program that uses one-way encryption. The program should work as follows:

1. If it's the first time opening the program, ever, a window will show up asking the user to enter a username and password, as well as a security question. This first time, the password will not be hidden by black circles. Instead, it will be shown in plain text.
2. Then, the three fields will be encrypted using a caesar/shift cipher of 3 spots, and the 'encrypted' values will be saved into a file called info.txt in the source folder of the program.
3. The user will then be redirected to a log-in page, where they will re-enter their username and password to log in. Here, the password field is fixed so that the letters show up as black circles(not sure what this is called). A new int variable called loginAttempts is declared and initialized with the value 0.
4. After the user hits 'log-in', the system will use the same encryption method for the log-in details entered and compare them to the encrypted information in the text file. If both values match, then the user will be re-directed to the main screen of the program, having been granted access.
5. If not, then loginAttempts increments. After the 5th time, this happens, the user will be asked their security question. If the answer this wrong the first time, they will be booted from the program.

I have a few questions, as I'm having trouble creating this.

1. The dialog boxes I'm using to produce error messages are very confusing, and not seeming to work. I got the code to use them straight from the Oracle website and I'm still having trouble-- NetBeans has informed me that it 'cannot find symbol' for showInputDialog(the method I'm using to display the error message), but it's not suggesting that I'm missing any imports.

   ```
   String errorMessage = "Security Question: What was your favorite class in college?";

       String s = (String) JTextField.showInputDialog(
               null,
               errorMessage,
               "ERROR",
               JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
               JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
               null,
               securityAnswer);
   ```

The part that's given me an error is the word 'showInputDialog' itself, and I'm unsure why..? I would like for this particular dialog to appear with a text field in it so that the user can enter the answer to the security question in there. However, the code doesn't even seem to be working.

On the Oracle page, this is the code that is given that is supposed to show a dialog box with an input field:

```
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame,
                    "Complete the sentence:\n"
                    + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                    "Customized Dialog",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    icon,
                    null,
                    "ham");

//If a string was returned, say so.
if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
    setLabel("Green eggs and... " + s + "!");
    return;
}

//If you're here, the return value was null/empty.
setLabel("Come on, finish the sentence!");
```

But the word *frame* creates an error in the Netbeans GUI, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work. All I want is to create a text box that looks like this:

[image: dialog with text field input]

but I don't know how to do that in a way that would work.

2. The way that I've set up my program, I've made multiple jFrame components(different classes), and I've set it up so that if you were to try and access a different frame, the frame you were currently on would turn invisible. For example:

   *(a user is on the main screen, and they click on a button that says 'Add Appointment.')*
   addAppointment a = new addAppointment();

   a.setVisible(true);

   a.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

   this.dispose();

And this works for literally all of my program except for the log-in page!

```
public createUserPass() throws IOException {
        String path="\\src\\Schedulemanager\\pkg\\info.txt";
             file = new File(path); //creates new File
                if (file.exists()) { //make a new file if it's not already existent
                    logIn loginPage = new logIn();
                    loginPage.setVisible(true);
                    loginPage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    this.dispose();
                    this.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    file.createNewFile(); //creates the new file
                    initComponents();
                }
    }
```

This is the 'main' class in the program that will run if the .jar file is clicked. What it's supposed to do is check if the *info.txt* file exists. If it does, then obviously the user has already set login information, and it should close itself and open an instance of the logIn class, which is the jFrame that handles the log-in functions once the information has been set. However, it doesn't work! It opens the new logIn class, but it doesn't dispose of the original one where you set the information, to begin with.

It's crucial that the original jFrame is hidden so that the user can't just set a new password every single time they run the program! How can I fix this?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Is this just a fun project or are you actually going to use it in a production environment?

Comment: @LukePark school project. they dont have high expectations for it though since we're just learning java.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and post it here? Also have you checked that the `if` is used? You could put `System.out.println("If case triggered");` or something similar there and see, if the if is called at all.